# C# - <T> object casting

Tags: c#, com, casting, queryinterface

As far as I know, if we're dealing with `COM` interfaces, any simple cast will usually trigger the `QueryInterface` routine, which is used to determine if the object actually implements the corresponding `COM` interface.

```
object whatever;
IComInterface casted = (IComInterface) whatever;
```

Hence, the following code, depending on the compiler and optimizations *might trigger* the `QueryInterface` in the internal object casting implementation:

```
IComInterface comInteface;

// I guess nothing COM-related happens here, but I might be wrong
object whatever = comInteface; 

// This might or might not trigger the 'QueryInterface' call.
IComInterface comInterface2 = (IComInteface) whatever;
```

---

### Q:

Suppose I have a generic `List<T>` instance:

```
List<IComInterface> list = new List<IComInterface>();
```

Now, do I have a strong guarantee that the following code would not trigger the `QueryInterface`-based cast?

```
List<IComInterface> list = new List<IComInterface>();
IComInterface comInterface = (...); // Somehow got it.
list.Add(comInteface);
IComInterface retrieved = list[0];
```

- Using `ArrayList` instead of `List<T>` here actually results in the cast performed, because you have to get the corresponding `IComInterface` from your typeless `object` instance.
- However, in case of generics, I guess, everything should be done without casting, but I'm not actually sure about how they work under the surface.
- Is it possible that `List<T>` still somehow operates with `object` types (and, hence, will invoke the `QueryInterface`-based cast in the described scenario)?
- If the answer to the previous question is "no", is it true, that you can't guarantee the same for any possible `IList<T>`?

Comment: As far as I know I thought that .NET created an instance of a new type when you created a generic type - therefore the strongly typed generic won't use `System.Object` references - I may be wrong

Comment: I am not 100% sure about it, so writing comment, One thing is no casting will happen if you use List<IComInterface> another is that your second question is irrelevant cause List<IComInterface> implements IList<T>.

Comment: @GuruKara Second question, as I realize now, is stupid, because somebody can implement a `IList<T>`, which uses `object` to store data and then casts it back :) So, I guess, the question is only about `List<T>`.

Comment: It might be worth reading this: http://www.artima.com/intv/generics2.html - It seems to shed some light on what IL is generated and what the CLR is actually doing. Sounds like each generic type is treated separately - give it a read

Comment: The interesting bit is: 

Bruce Eckel: And you just need to cast. 

Anders Hejlsberg: No, you don't actually. We can share the native image, but they actually have separate VTables. I'm just pointing out that we do fairly aggressive code sharing where it makes sense, but we are also very conscious about not sharing where you want the performance. Typically with value types, you really do care that List<int> is int. You don't want them to be boxed as Objects. Boxing value types is one way we could share, but boy it would be an expensive way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's a pretty decent guarantee, the compiler won't emit a Opcodes.Castclass IL instruction unless it has to.  The type matches so no need to for the cast.

This should not in general concern you.  The QI implementation of a COM interface gets hammered for all kinds of reasons, internal to COM.  It is always very fast, comparing a guid takes but a handful of nanoseconds.

Comment: Thank you, the question was purely academic and I was not concerned with the performance of the cast (that would obviously be premature).

Comment: Odd, if it is not perf then why are you academically interested?  Kinda hard to properly answer balloon questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of generic *type instances* (e.g. `List<IComInterface>`) as of classes created from generic *type definitions* (e.g. `List<T>`) by literally replacing the name `T` with the name `IComInterface`. The type is not "erased" the way it is done in some languages (most notably, Java), it is kept with the generic type instance, so that all variables declared as type `T` in the generic type definition remain strongly typed in the generic type instance.

In case of a `List<IComInterface>`, there is no cast to or from `object` as long as you insert objects that are known to be of `IComInterface` type at compile time. This is the case in the code from your post, but it may not always be true. For example, when you insert a dynamically typed object, the compiler will add a cast:

```
dynamic comInteface = ...
list.Add(comInteface); // There will be an implicit cast here
```